# How do I use the Azure Go SDK to work with role assignments?

Tags: azure, go, sdk, azure-rest-api, azure-rbac

How can I use the [Azure Go SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go) to work with role assignments? For example, how can I use it to list the role assignments that a particular principal has?

After consulting its documentation, I was able to figure out how to create clients for various Azure services, but I wasn't able to figure this out for working with role definitions in particular. After checking Stack Overflow for whether this problem has been addressed, I found some questions with answers, but they were for other programming languages such as .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK is divided into multiple Go modules. The documentation for the SDK itself starts at a [reference page](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk) that lists the modules but does not explain how to get started.

On another [Azure docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authentication-service-principal), there are instructions for authenticating the Go SDK using environment variables for the credentials associated with the service principal you want to use with the SDK -
`AZURE_TENANT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`. If you do not already have a service principal to use with the SDK, you will need to [create one using Microsoft Entra ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-service-principal-portal) (formerly known as Azure AD).

With these environment variables set, you can use `NewDefaultAzureCredential` from package [`azidentity`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity) to create a credential variable that can be used with any client from the SDK.

You cannot use this credential directly to create a client for working with role definitions. Instead, you must first create a client factory. The client factory must be created using the correct Go package, where there is a Go package for each Azure API. For working with role assignments, the package is [`armauthorization`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/authorization/armauthorization/v2).

Then, you can use the client factory to create a `*RoleAssignmentsClient` and use the client. You also need to use the subscription ID of the subscription for the scope you're working with.

Complete code example (assumes env vars described above are set):

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/authorization/armauthorization/v2"
)

func main() {
    subscriptionID := "<subscription-id>"

    cred, _ := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)

    // Initialize a client factory using the credential. The subscription ID
    // used to create the factory is used in many API requests made using clients
    // created from the factory. For example, the "list for subscription"
    // request shown below.
    clientFactory, _ := armauthorization.NewClientFactory(subscriptionID, cred, nil)

    // Get the client to be used from the factory.
    client := clientFactory.NewRoleAssignmentsClient()

    // To demonstrate that the client was created properly, test the client by
    // using it to get the first page of a list of all of the role assignments
    // within the subscription.
    pager := client.NewListForSubscriptionPager(nil)
    page, _ := pager.NextPage(context.TODO())

    fmt.Printf("Role assignments in subscription: %v\n", page.Value)
}
```

Example output:

```
Role assignments in subscription: [0xc0002b8080 0xc0002b80a0]
```

Note that they are pointers when they come back from the API, and that I have two principals in my example. They are:

- The user that was automatically created when I created my Azure account
- A service principal that I manually created by creating an application in Microsoft Entra ID, which I am using to authenticate this example

Note: I created this answer because I wasn't able to find docs that were useful to me right away. Eventually, I found docs [in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/resourcemanager/authorization/armauthorization). These can be used for further reference.